# clearInterval не останавливает таймер и таймер не перезапускается по новой

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

У меня есть список div-ов, каждый div имеет свой таймер, который зависит от даты, когда он должен быть удалён, после чего div удаляется из списка. Напротив каждого дива есть кнопка - «обновить», при нажатии я отправляю идентификатор дива через ajax, а на бэке меняю время, когда значение должно быть удалено. Я записываю значение в атрибут даты. Сделал общую функцию таймера. И если данные возвращаются успешно, я пытаюсь остановить таймер и запустить его заново, но ничего не меняется - таймер не перезапускается. Как я могу это исправить?

```
var counter;
function startCount(dot) {
    const interv = setInterval(() => {
        const currSeconds = Math.round(new Date() / 1000);
        const deletingTime = Number(dot.data('time'));              
        const timeLeft = deletingTime - currSeconds;
        if (timeLeft < 0) return clearInterval(counter);                
        dot.siblings().html(formatTime(timeLeft));              
        var timerText = dot.siblings().html();              
        if(timerText === '00:00'){
            dot.closest('tr').css('display', 'none');
        };           
    }, 1000);
  return interv;
}         
$('.update-dots').each(function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    var deletingTime = Number($(this).data('time'));    
    var currentTime = Math.round(new Date() / 1000);;
    var liveCircle = deletingTime - currentTime;
    counter = startCount(obj);                  
});
$('.update-dots').each(function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    $(this).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/ajax/update-timer',
                data: {
                'id': $(this).attr('id'), 
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                obj.attr('data-time', data);
                clearInterval(counter);
                counter = startCount(obj);          
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно дело в том, что у вас глобальный id таймера затирается последней итерацией в цикле `each`. Сделайте переменную с id таймера локальной или поместите её в какой-то контекст, отвечающий только за один блок. Например так:

```
function startCount(dot) {
    const interv = setInterval(() => {
        const currSeconds = Math.round(new Date() / 1000);
        const deletingTime = Number(dot.data('time'));              
        const timeLeft = deletingTime - currSeconds;
        if (timeLeft < 0) return clearInterval(counter);                
        dot.siblings().html(formatTime(timeLeft));              
        var timerText = dot.siblings().html();              
        if(timerText === '00:00'){
            dot.closest('tr').css('display', 'none');
        };           
    }, 1000);
  return interv;
}

$('.update-dots').each(function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    // тут были зачем-то переменные, которые нигде не используются
    var counter = startCount(obj);
    
    obj.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/ajax/update-timer',
                data: {
                'id': $(this).attr('id'), 
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                obj.attr('data-time', data);
                clearInterval(counter);
                counter = startCount(obj);          
            }
        });
    });
});
```